# UIScrollView decelerationRate with pagingEnabled

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

`UIScrollView` has a `decelerationRate` property that can be used to modify, well, the deceleration rate of a scroll view. But it’s not taken into account when `pagingEnabled = YES`. Whatever the deceleration rate, it has the same speed. Does somebody have a solution?

Comment: i've got the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: As the lack of comments and answers suggest it, no, I haven't found at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is old, but [here's a solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858073/1367622).

I had to set `pagingEnabled = NO` and manually implement the paging functionality. If you have a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled = YES`, then setting the `decelerationRate` property will not have any effect on the speed of the paging (as you've found out).

Comment: Wow, didn't look at this thread for soooo long. I eventually did found the same solution, and forgot to update. So let's grant you the points ;)

Comment: @Cyrille Thanks :) ...I thought it might save someone else some time searching for the answer.