# Sensitivity/Scroll speed of UIScrollView with paging

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want UIScrollView to scroll fast after fast sweep, [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Dug07Nt_dk).
Although, when paging is turned on, the scroll works [one page at a time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGLneA6hkWk).
Is it possible to scroll fast, when paging is enabled with a flick of a finger without manually implementation using gesture recognizers?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I wish there was a good solution to this. It seems there are two ways of implementing this: manually implementing gesture recognizers or manually implementing paging.

Comment: Yes Its possible I had implemented before 6 months. you can do manually be gesture recognizers..

Comment: @JohnWhite, if you have the implementation somewhere, I will be more than grateful. Instead of starting from scratch, there will be some working solid basis.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward, however you must implement the paging aspect yourself (which is fairly simple). You don't need gesture recognizers.

## Swift

First, adjust your **UIScrollView** deceleration rate:

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

Assume we have an array of content — let's call it `yourPagesArray`. In your **UIScrollViewDelegate**, implement the following method:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
{
    //This is the index of the "page" that we will be landing at
    let nearestIndex = Int(CGFloat(targetContentOffset.pointee.x) / scrollView.bounds.size.width + 0.5)

    //Just to make sure we don't scroll past your content
    let clampedIndex = max( min( nearestIndex, yourPagesArray.count - 1 ), 0 )

    //This is the actual x position in the scroll view
    var xOffset = CGFloat(clampedIndex) * scrollView.bounds.size.width

    //I've found that scroll views will "stick" unless this is done
    xOffset = xOffset == 0.0 ? 1.0 : xOffset

    //Tell the scroll view to land on our page
    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = xOffset
}
```

You will also need to implement the following delegate method, to handle the case where the user lifts their finger gently without causing any scroll deceleration:

(Update: you may not need to do this under the latest iOS SDK. It seems like the above delegate method is now called when there is zero velocity.)

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
{
    if !decelerate
    {
        let currentIndex = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)

        let offset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width * currentIndex, y: 0)

        scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## Objective-C

Setting your deceleration rate:

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

Then your scroll view delegate implementation:

```
- (void) scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scroll withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    //This is the index of the "page" that we will be landing at
    NSUInteger nearestIndex = (NSUInteger)(targetContentOffset->x / scrollView.bounds.size.width + 0.5f);   

    //Just to make sure we don't scroll past your content
    nearestIndex = MAX( MIN( nearestIndex, yourPagesArray.count - 1 ), 0 );

    //This is the actual x position in the scroll view
    CGFloat xOffset = nearestIndex * scrollView.bounds.size.width;

    //I've found that scroll views will "stick" unless this is done
    xOffset = xOffset==0?1:xOffset;

    //Tell the scroll view to land on our page
    *targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(xOffset, targetContentOffset->y);
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if( !decelerate )
    {
        NSUInteger currentIndex = (NSUInteger)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width);

        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * currentIndex, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful succinct answer. Thanks! I might add that using the slow deceleration rate gives a more "fluid" scrolling action, i.e. it scrolls through a lot more pages before stopping.

Comment: Brilliant! `scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;` is the key to make the behavior more like `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;`, finally find out, thanks!

Comment: This still leads to jerky behavior whenever the velocity is pointing in the opposite direction from the new contentOffset from the current location.

Comment: **This doesn't work at all I'm afraid.**  The UIKit scrolling mechanism is much, much, MUCH, more complex than this.

Answer (score 4):

I think we can set scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO when our finger touch it. And then when the animation is stop ,open it .It works for me.
Hope it will help you.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

// at the end of scroll animation, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that allows for fast scrolling, and snaps when the speed is slow, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRkxd.jpg

We need 4 variables:

```
var dragging = false
var lastOffset: CGPoint = .zero
var lastOffsetCapture: TimeInterval = .zero
var isScrollingFast: Bool = false
```

We need a helper function:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    var currentPage:Int{
        return Int((self.contentOffset.x+(0.5*self.frame.size.width))/self.frame.width)
    }
}
```

Then we need delegate methods:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let timeDiff = currentTime - lastOffsetCapture
    let captureInterval = 0.1
        
    if timeDiff > captureInterval {
        let distance = currentOffset.x - lastOffset.x 
            let scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000
            let scrollSpeed = fabsf(Float(scrollSpeedNotAbs))
            
            if scrollSpeed > 0.3 {
                isScrollingFast = true
            } else {
                if isScrollingFast && !dragging && scrollSpeed > 0.1 {
                    isScrollingFast = false
                    snapCard()
                }
            }
            lastOffset = currentOffset
            lastOffsetCapture = currentTime
        }
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        dragging = true
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        dragging = false
        let currentPage = scrollView.currentPage
        let pageSize = YOUR PAGE SIZE
        if velocity.x == 0 {
            let rightOfCenter = scrollView.contentOffset.x - currentPage*pageSize > 0
            snapCard(force: true, moveRight: rightOfCenter)
            return
        }
        if fabsf(Float(velocity.x)) < 0.3 {
            snapCard(force: true, moveRight: velocity.x > 0)
        }
    }
    
    func snapCard(force: Bool = false, moveRight: Bool = true) {
        let currentPage = scrollView.currentPage
        let pageSize = YOUR PAGE SIZE
        if !force {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: currentPage * pageSize, y: 0), animated: true)
        } else {
            if currentPage != YOUR NUM PAGES -1 {
                scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageSize *(currentPage + (moveRight ? 1 : -1)), y: 0), animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```