# decelerationRate property doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm developing an app that displays a huge number of photos (about 650 photos) in a scroll view, to make this app function smoothly, i added only three UIImages in the scrollView, one represents first page, the second for the current one and that third for the next page, so when the user first launchs the app, the first image will load in the middle page, the last image will load in the previous page and the second image will load in the next page, when the user scrolls to right, the middle page will load second image, the previous page will load the first image and the next page will load the third image and so on ..

But when the user scrolls fast the bounds of the scrollview will appear preventing user from scrolling to next page and only will bounce.

My question is how to make scroll view scrolls faster so that `-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
 method will call faster that normal

I tried `decelerationRate` property as shown in the code below but i didn't notice any difference ! am i using it right or there's something wrong ?

Thanks in advance

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    scrollView = [[ScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    //scrollView.decelerationRate= UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 416);


    pageZero = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    pageOne = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];
    pageTwo = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 480)];


    //set array that holds images to be shown
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        [pages addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]];

//load photos
    [self loadPageWithId:0 onPage:1];
    [self loadPageWithId:2 onPage:0];
    [self loadPageWithId:1 onPage:2];

//add 3 UIImage objects to the scrollView
    [scrollView addSubview:pageZero];
    [scrollView addSubview:pageOne];
    [scrollView addSubview:pageTwo];


    //scroll to the middle page without animation
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,0,320,416) animated:NO];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(singleTap)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled = YES`, then setting the `decelerationRate` property will not have any effect on the speed of the paging (as you've found out).

To get around this, you will need to set `pagingEnabled = NO` and manually implement the paging functionality yourself. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561992/sensitivity-scroll-speed-of-uiscrollview-with-paging) for how to do this.