# How to reduce scrolling speed of UIScroll view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview in my iphone application. In the runtime i'm adding multiple content page in to that and users can scroll the content horizontally.

Im faciing a issue here . consider if the user scrolled it quickly then sometimes thr will be a delay loading content of the page.

Is it possible for me to reduce the scrolling speed whether user tries to scroll the view. i want to delay the speed of scrolling

hope every one understood my question 
Thanks

Comment: if my finger move 50px, but the page only scroll 30px? i feel the app is doing something wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13858073/1066828

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked this option

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

don't get confused with 'RateFast' it is decelerationRate which means slow down.

Comment: Thanks. i cheked it but its not enough . have u seen the BMW magazine apps.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't installed that app. but got your problem. if you still want to reduce the speed. I am not sure with the syntax but be can change by changing X, Y OFFSET by getting floating-point value from decelerationRate.