# Buttons to scroll textview up or down

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I know how to create a textview with scrolling capabilities, but that requires you to touch inside the textview and manually scroll the text up or down. 
I want to create a UITextview and two buttons. The buttons act as scroll buttons, one to scroll up, the other to scroll down, letting the user control the scrolling speed. 
Many of the examples I've seen concerns automatic scrolling to the bottom which isn't what I want.
Can anyone suggest a way to scroll one to three lines up or down when the buttons are pressed?
Many thanks!

Comment: How about just `setContentOffset` like 30 at a time?

Comment: Does it work with Textview or do I have to implement as Scrollview?

Comment: textview is a scrollview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561992/sensitivity-scroll-speed-of-uiscrollview-with-paging     it is about paging but there is also somethings about scrolling speed.  Maybe you can find something useful.

Comment: I’ll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func upButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let currentOffset = textView.contentOffset
        let padding : CGFloat = 10 // Change as your choice
        textView.setContentOffset(
            CGPoint(
                x: currentOffset.x,
                y: currentOffset.y - padding < 0 ? 0 : currentOffset.y - padding
            ),
            animated: true
        )

    }


    @IBAction func downButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let currentOffset = textView.contentOffset
        let contentHeight = textView.contentSize.height
        let padding : CGFloat = 10.0 // Change as your choice
        textView.setContentOffset(
            CGPoint(
                x: currentOffset.x,
                y: currentOffset.y + padding > contentHeight ? contentHeight : currentOffset.y + padding
            ),
            animated: true
        )
    }
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

use this - update content offset when button click

```
@IBAction func btnUPClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if txtv.contentSize.height > txtv.contentOffset.y + txtv.frame.size.height // this condition checks textview reached at bottom
    {
    txtv.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:txtv.contentOffset.x , y:txtv.contentOffset.y + 10////change it according to requirement ) , animated: true)
    }

}

@IBAction func btnDownClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if txtv.contentOffset.y > 0 // // this condition checks textview reached at top
    {
    txtv.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:txtv.contentOffset.x , y:txtv.contentOffset.y - 10 //change it according to requirement  ) , animated: true)
    }
}
```

let me know if you have any issue...

Comment: For some reason it didn't work. Nothing happened when the buttons are pressed.

Comment: have you connect outlet of textview?

Comment: Yes, I replaced Joe's code with yours and changed the outlet name. Anyway, thanks for your help. I can see they work similar except yours is more compact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate`function to scroll the contentView up or down and also `UIScrollView` is the superClass of `UITextView` for more information read [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview).

First implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your class and use the following simple approach.

```
var scrollSpeed = CGFloat()

func toScrollUp(){
   scrollSpeed += 100
   myTextView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollSpeed, width: myTextView.frame.width, height: myTextView.frame.height), animated: true)
}

func toScrollDown(){
   scrollSpeed -= 100
   myTextView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollSpeed, width: myTextView.frame.width, height: myTextView.frame.height), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. As I was using UITextView I thought I'd go with Roy's solution.

Comment: @Bevan Visual output showing in my answer is actually a `UITextView`. Did you read the apple doc.

Comment: Yeah I know. I went with what I understand more. Sorry.