# Swift -prevent fast scrolling when collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a collectionView with paging enabled:

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

The collectionView is full screen (only 1 cell gets displayed at a time) and I have some code that runs in `scrollViewWillEndDragging`. When I scroll normal or semi fast `cellForItem` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging` are on the same page/indexPath.item. But when I scroll really fast they both get screwed up, cellForItem is always behind the current page

**How can I prevent the user from scrolling really fast when paging is enabled?

```
var currentItem: Int?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeue...

    currentItem = indexPath.item

    return cell
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let yAxis = targetContentOffset.pointee.y
    let page = Int(yAxis / collectionView.frame.height)

    guard let currentItem = currentItem else { return }
    if page == currentItem {

        // only do something when page and the current indexPath.item are equal which works fine with normal scrolling
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906553/4833705) worked:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```